# Rails: How do I use a javascript variable outside <script.../> but inside the view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In a view I have a script (javascript) that declares a variable after some deep processing. How can I use that variable outside the script boundaries in the same view page?

```
some_view.html.erb

<script>var seq = Sortable.sequence('list');</script>

# How to do this? Is it possible?

<%= sortable_element "list",
  :update => "order",
  :complete=> visual_effect(:highlight, "list"),
  :scroll => 'list',
  :url=>{:action=>"order", :order_init => seq} %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry I am a bit thick tonight. Maybe this helps explaining myself. I am trying to do something like this:

 <script>var seq = Sortable.sequence('list');</script>
 <%= sortable_element "list",
  :update => "order",
  :complete=> visual_effect(:highlight, "list"),
  :url=>{:action=>"order", :order_init => seq} %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible becasue Rails is a server-side language and javascript is executed on client side.

What you are looking for is [**AJAX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) functionality (asynchronous JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

If it is truly javascript that declares the variable after JavaScript processing, then you need to work the other way around. Like this (Move the `script` block below the HTML or this example will fail):

```
<h2> Hello, my name is <span id="name"></span></h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var name = "World";
   document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
</script>
```

That way after the script runs, the name would be replaced in the HTML on the client side.